# How to find attribute that "occurred only once" - relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

I have a table named:
 project(pId,cId)

and I am trying to find projects ids that only one company is working on them, using relational algebra.

I thought about using join and finding those pIds the occur more than once and then using subtraction but not sure how should I write it.

I cannot use count in my relational algebra and also not the !=

Comment: This is likely a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS There are many relational algebras. They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give a reference and/or definition for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. PS Ids present 1 time are all ids minus ids present 2 or more times. PS Show parts you can do & ask re being stuck. [mre]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relational Algebra “Only Once” or “Exists once”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26324811/3404097) [How to find all tuples in a table if and only if the tuple appears once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19482046/3404097) [Relational algebra, Find unique Names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50901458/3404097)

Comment: Hmm a faq @philipxy? Note the last para: cannot use count (nor presumably other aggregate operators), nor a theta-join with `≠` -- which I presume is what "not the !=" is saying -- strange because `≠` is allowed by every variety of RA, back to Codd 1972.

Comment: @AntC I don't understand your comment. I said how to do it with minus & self-join in my first comment then my next comment gave 3 links. What operators are not allowed doesn't mean much when they don't say what operators are allowed, but I didn't mention count or unequijoin anyway.

Comment: philipxy actually before posting I checked all links you provided and was not able to find an answer for my question. but I'll take a note of the other things said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the variety of Relational Algebra at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), explanation below, plus assignment to relation variables for intermediate results.

```
crosscid := project ⋈ ρ<cid2/cid>(project);
multicid := crosscid \ σ<cid = cid2>(crosscid);
result := π<pid>(project) \ π<pid>(multicid);
```

Where wikipedia shows subscripted components of operators, I show in angle brackets `< >`.

`crosscid` is the cross-product of all `cid`s for each `pid`, obtained by creating a duplicate of the `project` relation with `cid` renamed. Note this includes tuples with `cid == cid2`.

`multicid` is `crosscid` filtered to only the `pid`s with multiple `cid`s, obtained by subtracting the tuples in `crosscid` with `cid == cid2`. (This is the 'work round' for the limitation that we're not allowed to use `!=`.)

`result` is the `pid`s from the original `project` relation subtract the `pid`s with multiple `cid`s.

Comment: might be my mistake about not using the ≠ , need to check it again. either way, you helped a lot and I know what to change. Thank you :)